# Unable to connect localhost:8080 with Airflow

Tags: docker, airflow

I am doing this tutorial:
[image]

I installed the code in VS to create a docker and it's running:
[image]

[image]

But when I try to access on the browser with localhost:8080 doesn't works:
[image]

In the cmd:

[image]

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if any processes are using the port by running the following in cmd prompt:

netstat -a -n -o | find "8080"

Comment: When I execute this command I just see the process 21576 (the same that I showed in the post when I showed the screenshoot of cmd)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).